# Custom Tailwind CSS colors in chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, tailwind-css

I have a React application that utilizes Chart.js for rendering charts. I want to customize the colors of labels in the chart using custom colors defined in my Tailwind CSS configuration. I have already set up custom colors in my tailwind.config.js and CSS files, but I'm unsure how to use these colors for my chart labels.

Here are the relevant components in my code:

**index.css:**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.theme-light {
  --labelColor: #000000;
}

.theme-dark {
  --labelColor: #ffffff;
}
```

**tailwind.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        labelColor: 'var(--labelColor)',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**chart.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(...registerables);

const Graph = ({ chartData }) => {
  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          color: **labelColor**,
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          display: true,
          color: **labelColor**,
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          display: true,
          color: **labelColor**,
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const datasets = [];

  chartData.forEach((data, index) => {
    datasets.push({
      label: data.name,
      data: data.data,
    });
  });

  const data = {
    labels: chartData[0].labels,
    datasets: datasets,
  }

  return <Bar data={data} options={options} />;
}

export default Graph;
```

Any suggestions on the most appropriate way to use custom Tailwind colors in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use custom colors that way as tailwind custom colors are used often more with class attributes and then the way you are trying to use them depends on the compatibility of the chart.js modules to accept color as a custom tailwind color variable.
another way you can approach this is by declaring all of your custom colors in a separate file and exporting them as variables and then you will be able to use them by importing that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code from this [`Codepen`](https://codepen.io/kurkle/pen/KKpaYwx) all credits to author of the codepen.

```
function cssvar(name) {
  return getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(name);
}
```

react code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(...registerables);

export const cssVar = (name) => {
    return getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(name);
}

const Graph = ({ chartData }) => {
  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          color: cssVar('--labelColor'),
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          display: true,
          color: cssVar('--labelColor'),
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          display: true,
          color: cssVar('--labelColor'),
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const datasets = [];

  chartData.forEach((data, index) => {
    datasets.push({
      label: data.name,
      data: data.data,
    });
  });

  const data = {
    labels: chartData[0].labels,
    datasets: datasets,
  }

  return <Bar data={data} options={options} />;
}

export default Graph;
```